# Why use do-while as opposed to simple if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, do-while

Can anyone tell me why in the following code a do/while lop is used rather than a simple if statement:

```
function prev(elem){
do {
    elem = elem.previousSibling;
} while(elem && elem.nodeType != 1);
    return elem;
}
```

Why not:

```
function prev(elem){
if(elem && elem.nodeType != 1) {
    elem = elem.previousSibling;
    return elem;
}
```

Is there an advantage to using do/while?  Thanks!

Comment: For the same functionality you'd have to use an `else` with your `if` that calls the same function.

Comment: These both codesnippets work significantly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`do-while` will run once and continue running while the statement is true, while the `if-statement` will only run once.

In this instance it may be equivalent (depending on how the code and data is set up), but typically that is how `do-whiles` are used.

Comment: Thanks, @GrailsGuy.  I was just thinking about it the wrong way.  This makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to keep repeating until a certain condition is met, use the `do`,`for`, or `while` statement. If you only want to check something once, use the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using do while loop, then your statements will execute atleast once. Then a condition is checked and if the condition is not satisfied then the statement are not executed any more. But if you use the other option then first condition is checked and if the condition is satisfied then the statements are executed only once. Otherwise they are not executed even a single time.

Answer (score 0):

```
A While or Do While statement is a continuous loop until a condition is met.  
An If, Then, Else/Else If is a simple evaluative statement rather than a loop.
```

Here `do-while` will run atleast once, and will execute until while condition is met.
But in the `if-statement`, it'll check the condition first, and will execute once only and will return the response.